# Kendo Grid Ajax inside Kendo TabStrip Ajax (LoadContentForm) not displaying content

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, tabs, grid, strip

I want to put an Ajax Kendo Grid inside an Ajax Kendo TabStrip, but the grid never displays any of its values. (Even if the FireBug console indicates that the values have been correctly get...)

Is this a known issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

Ajax Kendo TabStrip :

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
.Name("portailClientsTabStrip")
    //.HtmlAttributes(new { style="height:100%" })
.Animation(animation =>
{
    animation.Enable(true);
    animation.Open(config =>
    {
        //config.Expand();
        config.Fade(FadeDirection.In);
        config.Duration(AnimationDuration.Fast);
    });
})
.Items(tabstrip =>
{
    tabstrip.Add().Text("Livraisons")
        .Selected(true)
        .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("Livraison"));

    tabstrip.Add().Text("Remplissage")
        .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("Remplissage"));

    tabstrip.Add().Text("Expéditions")
        .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("Expedition"));

    tabstrip.Add().Text("Collectes")
        .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("Collecte"));

    tabstrip.Add().Text("Annonces").LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("Annonce"));
})
.Events(e=>e
    .Select("portailClientsTabStripSelectHandler")
    .Activate("portailClientsTabStripActivate")
))
```

Ajax Kendo Grid inside the partial view Annonce :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Integraal.Models.Mouvement>()
.Name("grilleMouvements") // Préfixe du nom de la grille par l'identifiant de la vue partielle.
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_cli_code);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_detenteur_code);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_date_prev);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_date);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_prod_code);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_quantite);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_flag).Visible(false);
})
.Navigatable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))          //Colonnes réglables en largeur
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(r => r.Action("readAnnonces", "PortailClients"))
)
.Events(e => e.DataBound("grilleAnnoncesDataBound")))
```

Comment: i have used grids inside tabstrips several times without a problem. but i haven't used whatever odd bindings you are using there. It works well in plain javascript. :)

Comment: Show us the complete partial view code. Also check for any JS errors.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use LoadContentFrom for loading the grid inside the tabstrip

use `Content(@<text> @Html.Action("YourAction","YourController")</text>)`

Answer (score 0):

I have no JavaScript errors.

Here is my complete partial view code :

```
@model Integraal.Models.Mouvement
<script type="text/javascript">
function grilleAnnoncesDataBound(e) {

    //$('tr').each(function () {
    //    if ($(this).text() == 'Jane') { $(this).addClass('customClass') }
    //});
}
</script>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Integraal.Models.Mouvement>()
.Name("grilleMouvements") // Préfixe du nom de la grille par l'identifiant de la vue partielle.
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_cli_code);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_detenteur_code);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_date_prev);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_date);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_prod_code);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_quantite);
    columns.Bound(m => m.mvt_flag).Visible(false);
})
.Navigatable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))          //Colonnes réglables en largeur
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(r => r.Action("readAnnonces", "PortailClients"))
)
.Events(e => e.DataBound("grilleAnnoncesDataBound"))
)
```

And here are my controller's actions :

```
public PartialViewResult Annonce()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    public JsonResult readAnnonces([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        MouvementService service = new MouvementService();
        IEnumerable<Mouvement> liste = service.getMouvements("A");

        Dictionary<string, object> session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        session.Add("listeAnnonces", liste);
        GlobalSession.SetInSession<Dictionary<string, object>>("1", session);

        return Json(liste.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Hey Thomas, i am having the same issue like you. Do you solve your issue by any chance?

Comment: Hello, I have not resolve the problem... I now charge the content without using a Kendo TabStrip.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in your return statement when you return the Json.  Hope this helps

Example:

return Json(videos.VideoList.ToDataSourceResult(request),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);